# Dojo this.inherit throws 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callee' of undefined'

Tags: dojo

To facilitate a JsonRest store with a non-standard url scheme, I am trying to inherit JsonRest and override the `_getTarget(id)` function.  Here is what my inherited javascript class looks like:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dojo/store/JsonRest",
        ],
function(declare, JsonRest) {
    return declare(JsonRest, {
        _getTarget: function(id){
            var target = this.target;
            if(typeof id != "undefined"){
                if(target.indexOf("{id}") != -1) {
                    //use template
                    target = target.replace("{id}", id);
                } else {
                    target = this.inherited(id);
                }
            }
            return target;
        },
    });
});
```

However the line `target = this.inherited(id);` returns an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callee' of undefined`.

I looked at the docs, and I think I am doing it right:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/declare.html#calling-superclass-methods

What is the proper way to call the base class's `_getTarget(id)` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look closely the part of the documentation you linked, you are supposed to *literally* pass the `arguments` object to `this.inherited` - that's what contains the `callee` property it is looking for (and will include the `id` and any other arguments anyway, to be passed along to the superclass).

A few paragraphs in, the documentation also explains how to call `this.inherited` with arguments other than the same ones passed, if necessary: you can pass custom arguments in an array *after* `arguments`, i.e. `this.inherited(arguments, [ ... ])`.  `arguments` always has to be first.